# Disable #warning just for one header

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

In **C**/C++ code I try to port, a deprecated system header is included:

From the header:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#warning "this header is deprecated"
#endif
```

As we compile here with `gcc -Wall -Werror`, compilation stops.
In the long run, replacing the use of deprecated functions is best, but for now I want to disable just this warning.

Compiling without `-Werror` of course works, but as this is part of a completely automated build process, I prefer not to do that.

Including the header with `#undef`ing `__GNUC__` before and `#define`ing it afterwards is a possibility, but I'm worried of the side effects inside the included header.

Is there a way to either disable `#warning` or relax `-Werror` just for one header?

Comment: There is no such thing as "C/C++ code".

Comment: There's a reason that things become deprecated.  Instead of trying to hack your way around the problem, eliminate the problem and stop using the deprecated header.  If they deprecated the header, then there is certainly a better, more modern way to accomplish your goals.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It's a mix of C and C++ code.

Comment: @ThomasErker: That doesn't make sense, unless you are referring to a program comprised of individual translation units written in C and C++, varyingly... but then this is not a minimal testcase. Do you mean to say it is C++ code that makes use primarily of C idioms?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: A library in C-ish C++ that has to be used by C and C++ and some helper/example programs that have to be compileable as C and C++. So the solution has to be C and C++ compatible. I was expecting "C/C++ code" to be understood in the same way as "Perl/Python code". Any idea for a better wording?

Comment: @ThomasErker: Sounds like a C library to me.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with a (GCC specific) [diagnostic pragma](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas)

If you surround the include with the following it will disable any warnings caused by `#warning`.

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wcpp"
#include "header.h"
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Note that if you change the `ignored` to `warning` in the above the compiler still prints the warnings - it just doesn't act on the `-Werror` flag for them.

Comment: This only works for c, not c++: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80650

Answer (score 2):

This disables precisely one type of warnings, the #warning directive, so I presume it's the safest solution to this problem:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-W#warnings"
#include <evilheader.h>
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

(**Edit**: Sorry, turns out gcc is actually clang on my system, so may not work with your genuine gcc)

Comment: I just tried that with gcc 4.7.2 and it looks like it is a clang specific feature I'm afraid.

Comment: @SimonGibbons yep. It's funny how clang imitates GCC (e.g. `pragma GCC diagnostic`) but does it better than GCC itself :)

Comment: Upvoted even though it doesn't work with genuine gcc because my gcc is really clang too.

Comment: Hang on.. some systems link `gcc` to Clang?!?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit on OS X yes. Clang is 99% compatible on the command line level, so to make your open-source package builds headache-free it simply links gcc to clang if the former is not available.

Comment: @mojuba: That's absolutely terrible!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Apple is a terrible company, they want to kill gcc and other innocent compilers.